# Iterating over results of .itertuples() is too slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df -> ["user_id", "num_posts", "posts" ...]

My df is made of rows containing data for reddit user-accounts; where for each row "posts" contains a series of separate posts by that user.

The number of posts ranges up to 6000 for certain users.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["user_id","posts"])
for row in df.itertuples():         
    for post in row[ : len(row[3])]:  
        new_row = [row[1], post ]
        data.loc[len(data)] = new_row
```

It seems the inner for-loop, that iterates over results from itertuples makes this terribly slow!

Even if I cap the maximum number of posts to be grabbed  for a single user with 100, the code doesn't return for hours even running on a high powered remote server!

***Any thoughts on how to improve the runtime?***

Comment: can you copy/paste `df.head(10)` inside your question to show your data, please?

Comment: I'm not that good at Pandas, but it seems unusual that you're increasing `data.loc` one element at a time using indexing.  Perhaps the code could run faster if you initialized `result = []`, changed the last line to `result.append(new_row)`, and as a final step, set `data.loc` to the list of new results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code verse 'concat' method with list comprehension' and I've got it 12 times faster with list comprehension:

```
data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[row[1], post] for post in row], columns=["user_id", "posts"])
                  for row in df.itertuples()], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: thank you - this absolutely solved my problem! I can grab all posts in just a few seconds now :)